# WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED not triggering

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

**WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED** is not getting detected when i shut down the worklight server in my android mobile. but its working fine in browser. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the [Working Offline](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/OfflineMode.zip) sample app in Worklight v5.0.6.1 and received both disconnectDetected and connectDetected events in my Android device running Android OS v4.0.4.

Prior to v5.0.6.x even if close the server, the port  would still be taken (in Jetty) and this could cause problem. Closing Eclipse frees the port. In 5.0.6.x this is fixed.

Make sure you are using the latest Worklight version*, and that the sample app you have downloaded is also the latest available from the Getting Started page (the page is currently down for maintenance, [you can get it from here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html), search for "working offline").

You can download/upgrade your Worklight by visiting the Eclipse Marketplace from the Help menu.

Other than that, you'll need to edit your question with some more information:

- Your Worklight version
- Developer Edition or Consumer/Enterprise Edition
- Your Android device OS version